# How do I configure Prettier not to wrap my multiline interface property value in a way that breaks @typescript-eslint/key-spacing?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, prettier, typescript-eslint

Prettier keeps formatting my `icon` property like this:

```
export interface ListIconProps {
  icon:
    | (OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, 'svg'>> & { muiName: string })
    | (() => JSX.Element)
  primary?: boolean
}
```

which breaks my linter:

```
   8:3  error  Missing space before value for key 'icon'  @typescript-eslint/key-spacing
  28:3  error  Missing space before value for key 'icon'  @typescript-eslint/key-spacing
```

How can I configure Prettier to format this in a way that conforms with the default rules for key-spacing?

Also tried making an exception in eslint.js which didn't go too well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the ESLint key-spacing rule for your project or for specific files or lines using comments, such as `/* eslint-disable key-spacing */` or `// eslint-disable-line key-spacing`. This will allow Prettier to format your code without triggering ESLint errors.

For example:

```
export interface ListIconProps {
  icon: // eslint-disable-line key-spacing
    | (OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, 'svg'>> & { muiName: string })
    | (() => JSX.Element)
  primary?: boolean
}
```